# Jquery - check if checkboxes are checked one at a time

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Basically what I need to do is run through a series of checkbox if it is checked I need to submit its value using ajax. Now I can't seem to find a way to run through each checkbox one at a time. Here's the code on my page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){

});
});

<?php
/**
 * Include vB core.
 */ 
require_once('./global.php');
require_once(DIR . '/includes/functions_bigthree.php');
require_once(DIR . '/includes/functions_forumlist.php');

/**
 * Grab the divisions from the database.
 */
$query = $db->query_read("SELECT division FROM rollcall_divisions");
while($array = $db->fetch_array($query)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' value=".$array[division].">".$array[division]."<br>";
}
?>

<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Comment: Have you submitted the relevant portion of the code completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) for your checkboxes and the submit the ajax request for them using the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    // submit your ajax request        
});
```

To actually submit the ajax request, jQuery has the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Comment: You used a radio instead of a checkbox but I get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) filter selector and [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $(':checkbox').each(function(){
     if ($(this)).is(':checked') {
       // your code....
     }
  });
});
```

The `:checkbox` targets all checkboxes on the page and then `each` is used to iterate over each of them. Later in the condition `is` is used with `:checked` filter selector to know which of these checkboxes is actually checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourform').find(':checkbox').each( function() {
    // do ajax stuff on $(this)
});
```